# If i call a function from a function without passing the calle as parameter to main function, does that mean its JavaScript Callback

Tags: javascript

Most of the time when i call a function from a function, i just don’t pass the calling function as parameter to the main or containing function. Does that mean i am using callback ?

Callback Eg:

```
// global variable
var allUserData = [];

// generic logStuff function that prints to console
function logStuff (userData) {
    if ( typeof userData === "string")
    {
        console.log(userData);
    }
    else if ( typeof userData === "object")
    {
        for (var item in userData) {
            console.log(item + ": " + userData[item]);
        }

    }

}

// A function that takes two parameters, the last one a callback function
function getInput (options, callback) {
    allUserData.push (options);
    callback (options);

}

// When we call the getInput function, we pass logStuff as a parameter.
// So logStuff will be the function that will called back (or executed) inside the getInput function
getInput ({name:"Rich", speciality:"JavaScript"}, logStuff);
```

Is it a Callback ?

```
function say1(){
   say2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a callback is a function that's passed as a parameter to another function. In your top example it is an *synchronous callback* as it will get executed right away.

Your bottom example is not a callback, the `say2` function is not given as a parameter to the `say1` function.

Comment: What is it called then ? and what is the difference ?

Comment: Well it's a simple function call. The main difference is in the way it's predetermined at write tim, whereas a callback is "executable data" that you provide at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Callback is a function which can be called later at any time when you need.

First define the function:

```
function f1(){
...
}
```

Now, calling that function is called the callback:

```
f1();
```

And, yes you can use parameters as you used in the function.

---

If you want to use in the parameter then do like below:

```
function f2(f1){
  f1(); //f1 callback is used as defined previously
}
```

Comment: C-link Nepal Both the function that i have written in my questions are callback then ? so its  not necessary to pass it as parameter rite ?

Comment: If you've parameters defined in the function then use, else it wouldn't make any sense to use those arguments..